# How to upgrade a Laravel project from 8 to 9

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel 8 project I want to upgrade to Laravel 9.

I read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#upgrade-9.0).

I updated my `composer.json` file as explained below. Now this file is like that (extract):

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2|^8.0",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.17",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.6"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
    "laravel/dusk": "^6.20",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
},
```

When I run a `composer update`, I have this error:

```
Problem 1
    - illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I also tried to delete the lock file and run `composer install`. I have the same error. I also tried to remove the version "^7.2" from the composer.json to have only "^8.0". Without success.

What can I try next?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? `composer why-not php 8.0`  could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was because the `"spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.6"`.

I removed it and installed a later version. And all is OK now.

Now it is this version: `"spatie/laravel-translatable": "^6.0"`